# Como passar um Char para o banco?

Tags: java, oracle, char

Como faço para passar um `Char` para o Banco?

Erro

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: valor muito grande para a coluna "SYSTEM"."USUARIO"."TP_SEXO" (real: 2, máximo: 1)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3714)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1378)
    at br.com.younews.dao.UsuarioDao.adiciona(UsuarioDao.java:33)
    at br.com.younews.teste.TesteUsuarioDao.main(TesteUsuarioDao.java:20)
```

meu código:

```
package br.com.younews.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.younews.beans.Usuario;
import br.com.younews.conexao.ConexaoFactory;

public class UsuarioDao {
    private Connection conn;
    private List<Usuario> user = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

    public UsuarioDao() throws Exception {
        this.conn = new ConexaoFactory().getConnection();
    }

    public Usuario adiciona(Usuario usuario) throws SQLException{
        String sql = "INSERT INTO USUARIO (EMAIL_USUARIO, NM_USUARIO, SENHA_USUARIO, TP_SEXO, DT_NASCIMENTO, FOTO_USUARIO, NM_LOCALIZACAO, NM_SOBRENOME, NM_NOME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, usuario.getEmail());
        st.setString(2, usuario.getNmUsuario());
        st.setString(3, usuario.getSenha());
        st.setInt(4, usuario.getSexo());
        st.setString(5, usuario.getDataNasc());
        st.setString(6, usuario.getFotoPerfil());
        st.setString(7, usuario.getLocalizacao());
        st.setString(8, usuario.getNome());
        st.setString(9, usuario.getSobrenome());
        st.execute();
        st.close();
        return usuario;
    }

    public List<Usuario> listarUsuario() throws Exception{
        List<Usuario> user = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT P.CD_USUARIO FROM USUARIO P LEFT JOIN USUARIO_AMIGO E ON E.USUARIO_CD_USUARIO1 = E.CD_AMIGO");
        ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.setIdLogin(rs.getString("CD_USUARIO"));
            usuario.setNmUsuario(rs.getString("NM_USUARIO"));
        }
        rs.close();
        p.close();
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o tipo de dados no banco?

Comment: TP_SEXO CHAR(1 BYTE) cadastramos assim

Comment: Quase certeza que se tu trocar para `CHAR(1 CHAR)` vai funcionar. Tu pode tentar isso?

Comment: A *tag* é SQL server, mas o erro é Oracle. Pode consertar a *tag*?

Comment: Jbueno, funcionou, mudei para CHAR(2 CHAR), mas minha duvida, eu passei como "int" porque não sei como passar um char, mas no banco o correto não deveria ser 1?

Comment: consertei cara :)

Comment: Ahhhhhh, a dúvida é o `set` do `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: isso mesmo cara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução é trocar no seu `PreparedStatement` de `setInt()` para `setString()`.

```
st.setString(4, String.valueOf(usuario.getSexo()));
```

Usando o `setInt()` a variável `char` será convertida para `Integer` ao enviar para o banco. E ao converter um `char` para `Integer` o valor enviado é o equivalente ao código [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) do `char`, por isso que estava sendo salvo **77**, ao invés de **M** no banco.

Aqui vai uma tabela de como o JDBC trata os tipos Java:

```
Tipo JDBC              Tipo Java
-------------------------------------------
CHAR                   String
VARCHAR                String
LONGVARCHAR            String
NUMERIC                java.math.BigDecimal
DECIMAL                java.math.BigDecimal
BIT                    boolean
BOOLEAN                boolean
TINYINT                byte
SMALLINT               short
```

Comment: mas assim vou ter que mudar minha classe beans correto ? porque la eu deixei como CHAR

Comment: Não jovem. Vou complementar a pergunta com a explicação.

Comment: ok, eu entendi, desculpa se parece lengo nisso, sou muito novato cara, primeira vez que estou trabalhando com conexão, agora ele me retorna o seguinte erro "The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, char)"

Comment: Sem problemas, ninguém nasceu sabendo. Quanto ao erro, leia de novo ali na resposta a parte do `setString()`.

Comment: acabei de ver rs, muito obrigado cara!!!

Answer (score 3):

A solução real é usar um [`NCHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i14946) no banco de dados. Este tipo é o adequado para guardar caracteres Unicode, como é o caso do usado no Java. Se optar por não fazer isto terá que fazer uma conversão com possível perda de valor.

Não recomendo. Também não recomendo usar `CHAR(2)`. Até vai resolver por coincidência. Ele está gravando 1 caractere que deveria ocupar 2 *bytes* em uma espaço para 2 caracteres. *Byte* e caractere são conceitos diferentes e intercambiá-los é pedir para ter problemas. Uma hora isto não vai funcionar. Fique com a solução onde você grava 1 caracteres - que é o que deseja - que permite ser *multibyte*, que é o caso do `NCHAR`.

Pelo comentário abaixo acho que o problema nem era Unicode. Provavelmente se usar um `setString()` no lugar de um `setInt()` vai resolver o problema, sem mudar o tipo no banco de dados. Me parece que está gravando ASCII mesmo. Só o uso do método errado é que estava forçando ter um texto maior.

Comment: eu fiz isso cara, mas como deixei "st.setInt" ele ta cadastrando com valor "77" sabe como conserto isso?